# 2 drives each with a different windows version

Tags: operating-systems

I just bought a new PC with windows 10 and upgraded graphics, mother board and other candy to game with. I like window 7 and have been using it for a few years and have many things I like better with W7 that I can't do with W10. I just want to open the PC case and put my old hard drive in it and switch back and forth at my leisure. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot just stick the Windows 7 disk in a new Windows 10 PC. You will have totally different device drivers and hardware, which will almost certainly cause Windows 7 to Blue Screen (crash) while booting.

You can export your files from Windows 7 to 10 using the Backup and Restore utility, but that is as close as you can get.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, not just a Windows 7 disk, but the hard drive from my old computer, in an empty drive bay in my new PC.

Comment: my other option would be to get another HDMI cable to plug into my monitor/tv to swap between the 2 PC's. Both have USB access in the front, so I would just have to transfer the mouse, keyboard and speakers back and forth as needed.

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear, I meant that you cannot install the old Windows 7 Hard Disk into the new PC. I mean, you can physically install and connect it, but it will not boot successfully. You could definitely keep using both PCs with a KVM switch, if that's an acceptable solution, e.g. https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817182157

Answer (score 0):

This is possible under some circumstances. My refurb HP laptop came with Win10. I swapped in the HDD from my Win8 HP laptop and it booted fine. The Win8 had no drivers for the SD card reader, so that hardware was unusable. It's possible there may be some drivers to let Win8 use this laptop's hardware. Some drivers can possibly be hacked to run on a version of Windows that they do not support. Be backed up and prepared for crashes and major recovery though.

Swapping the booted HDD is a big change, kind of like a brain transplant (or a body transplant, if you look at it the other way), so this topic is kind of advanced.

An idea to improve your chances - before swapping, use Win7 in the old PC to un-install the hardware-specific drivers. Windows will fall back to use generic / default drivers, which are supposed to run on any PC. Then swap, and boot Win7 in the new PC. Then maybe try to install drivers for the new hardware.

Also maybe try booting in Safe Mode? Of course make a backup of the partition first of all.

Comment: My orginal intent was to dual-boot Win 8 and 10, and gradually migrate. But have not found a way to make 10 look non-ugly, so I never boot it.

Comment: Windows 8 and Windows 10 were typically installed in UEFI mode. Windows 7 was typically BIOS. The suggestion to uninstall hardware specific drivers is generally correct but there are other considerations: https://superuser.com/a/1375513/931000

Answer (score 0):

You cannot even boot the old Windows 7 (BIOS) in a UEFI machine without enabling Legacy and changing the boot order - which will automatically result in **Windows 10 not booting**.

And if your Windows 7 came with the computer you **can't even legally use it in a different machine (OEM license)**.

Disregarding this last bit, you may reinstall Windows 7 in UEFI mode alongside Windows 10. You'll need a USB installation media that can be downloaded directly from Microsoft. Installing Windows 7 in UEFI mode requires a USB, it can't be installed with a DVD.